# How does RANK() work on multiple columns in Sql?

Tags: sql, transactions, teradata, rank

Could you please explain how does this piece of SQL work? `QUALIFY` selects first value, it's clear

```
QUALIFY RANK(column1 ASC, column2 ASC, column3 , column4)=1
```

What does `Rank()` do with next columns after column1 ?

Comment: I associate `qualify` with Teradata, so I added the tag.  Please be sure the database tag is correct on your questions.

Comment: It's independent of Teradata: RANK assignes the same number to the same group of columns, i.e. if the value of any of those 4 columns changes, the RANK is increased.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Snowflake has `qualify` clause as well

Comment: @Gandalf . . . True.  But it doesn't have the broken `rank()` function.

Answer (score 0):

First, this use of `RANK()` is HIGHLY discouraged.  See the [documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/8Ex9CS5XErnUTmh7zcrOPg).

The better way to write this is:

```
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 ASC, column3 , column4) = 1
```

This is equivalent to returning ALL the rows with the following conditions:

1. `column1` has the minimum value.
2. `column2` has the minimum value for everything in (1).
3. `column3` has the minimum value for everything in (2).
4. `column4` has the minimum value for everything in (3).

That is, the data is ordered by the four keys and the first row -- and all rows that match it on the four keys -- are returned.

Comment: Should be `ORDER BY column1, column2, column3 DESC, column4 DESC` because the old legacy syntax defaulted to `DESC`